# How to use strpos() in php when filtering an array

Tags: php, strpos, array-filter

I am trying to refine my array using strpos() , it`s works fine when i hardcode string manually but it fails if i pass the value using a variable.

Below code works fine.

```
  $filteredArray = array_filter($json_output, function($obj)
{ 
    return strpos(strtolower($obj->title), strtolower("Something"));
});
```

Below code does n`t work (Edit Posting full code for reference )

```
    <?php
$url = sprintf(
    '%s://%s/%s',
    isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http',
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
);    
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($parts['query'], $query);

if (!empty($query['key'])) { 
$keyword = $query['key'];
$jsonurl = "url";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$json_output = json_decode($json);
$filteredArray = array_filter($json_output, function($obj)
{ 
    return strpos(strtolower($obj->title), strtolower($keyword));
});
echo json_encode($filteredArray);

}
else
{
    echo "Gods must be crazy";
}
?>
```

it throws following error - Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty needle.

Can someone please point out where i am doing it wrong?

Comment: That's because your `$keyword` is empty! So check with `empty()` before you return  if `$keyword` is empty! otherwise return like false or so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use

```
$filteredArray = array_filter($json_output, function($obj) use ($keyword)
{ 
    return strpos(strtolower($obj->title), strtolower($keyword));
});
```

because it is in the scope of the function and you defined it at a higher level.

And also check with `empty` as was suggested in the comments.

Comment: Thanks it worked - bringing $keyword into the scope did the trick.

Comment: You can use `stripos` - a case insensitive analogue of `strpos`. And since the `stripos` / `strpos` functions may return "non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE", I suggest you to `return ( stripos($obj->title, $keyword) !== false );`